# How to make Pinterest button grab a real size blogger image instead a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I used this Pinterest button on my blog

```
<li><a class='pinterest share-tooltip share-tooltip-top' data-share-tooltip='Share on Pinterest' expr:href='&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;media=&quot; + data:post.firstImageUrl + &quot;&amp;description=&quot; + data:post.title' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-pinterest'/>Pinterest</a></li>
```

as you can see I'm using ***data:post.firstImageUrl*** as the source of the image ... but the problem is i made my fist image doesn't show in a full size only a thumbnail (medium size) ... so when i used this ***data:post.firstImageUrl*** ... the image that being shared only a thumbnail not the real one

here is the sample of thumbnail URL which i got from ***data:post.firstImageUrl***

```
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W-g2qYS-Kh0/V5gs0FvhpKI/AAAAAAAAFSY/yh_3p00aSA4-fRa65NH4cQ83iEngZhDeACLcB/s640/BMW-M5-30-Jahre-2014-1.jpg
```

and here is the full size image URL that i want

```
https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W-g2qYS-Kh0/V5gs0FvhpKI/AAAAAAAAFSY/yh_3p00aSA4-fRa65NH4cQ83iEngZhDeACLcB/s1600/BMW-M5-30-Jahre-2014-1.jpg
```

as you can see the different only come to this part xxx://xxx/xxx/**s640**/xxx and xxx://xxx/xxx/**s1600**/xxx ...

*my question is how do i change this URL part **s640** into this **s1600** and how to assign it into my pinterest button ?*

i had been seen someone using a JavaScript to change this URL part /**s640**/, he used it for auto resize thumbnail, I'm not familiar with JavaScript so I'm not really understand it, here is the code

```
img src="'+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'" alt="'+post_title+'"/
```

Comment: May you provide a working example in a jsbin/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use script from [this pastie](http://pastie.org/8519905). But it need a bit change.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function thumbnail_resize(image_url) {
  var image_size = 1600;
  image_tag = image_url.replace('/s640/','/s' + image_size + '/');
  if(image_url != "") {
    return image_tag;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Here we replaced the URL of image.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.write('&lt;a class=&quot;pinterest share-tooltip share-tooltip-top&quot; data-share-tooltip=&quot;Share on Pinterest&quot; href=&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<data:post.url/>&amp;media=' + thumbnail_resize(&quot;<data:post.firstImageUrl/>&quot;) + '&amp;description=<data:post.title/>&quot;&gt;PING&lt;/a&gt;');</script>
```

And here we pasted the link via JavaScript.